# How to destroy TaskScheduler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

how can I destroy this scheduler ?

```
@PostConstruct
private void startWatchingMonitor() {
    PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(this::watchingMonitor, trigger);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TaskScheduler#schedule`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html#schedule-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.Date-) returns a [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html?is-external=true).

You can then just use [`cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-):

```
@PostConstruct
private void startWatchingMonitor() {
    PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    ScheduledFuture future=scheduler.schedule(this::watchingMonitor, trigger);
    //...
    future.cancel();
}
```